# Попадание точки на внутреннюю границу?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net, freepascal

Есть алгоритм, он вычитывает попадает точка в окружность, на границу внешнюю/внутреннею или в фигуру внутри окружности. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой, он не корректно отображает информацию насчет попадания на внутреннею границу фигуры, которая внутри окружности. Например если задать координату `(-14; 0)` он выведет `"точка на внутренней границе"` а если например задать координату `(0; 3)`, что также попадает на границу, то он просто выведет `"точка входит область"`. Не могу понять где допустил оплошность, подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить?
Картинка окружности(красным это указаны координаты(высоты и ширина этой малой фигуры)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]>=0) or
       (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=-14)or
       (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]<=round(-b/2)) or
       (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]>=round(b/2))
    then t:=t+1;
    if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]>r*r) then begin 
       TextOut(65, f, ' - точка за границей области');
       f:=f+16;
    end
       else if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]=r*r) then begin 
          TextOut(65, f, ' - точка на внешеней границе');
          f:=f+16; 
       end
       else if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]>=0) or
               (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<-14) or
               (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]<round(-b/2)) or
               (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]>round(b/2))
               then begin 
                  TextOut(65, f, '- точка входит область');
                  f:=f+16;
               end
              else if ((x[i]=0) and (y[i]<15) and (y[i]=15)) or
                      ((x[i]=-14) and (y[i]<15) and (y[i]>-15)) or
                      ((y[i]=15) and (x[i]<0) and (x[i]>-14)) or
                      ((y[i]=-15) and (x[i]<0) and (x[i]>-14))
               then begin 
                    TextOut(65, f, ' - точка на внутренней границе');
                    f:=f+16;
                    end
               else begin
                    TextOut(65, f, ' - точка во внутренней фигуре');
                    f:=f+16;
                    end
     end;
```

Comment: `y[i]=15` вместо `y[i]>-15` — это опечатка в вопросе или в коде?.. к данной проблеме не относится, но не стоит сравнивать числа с плавающей точкой (если здесь они) на равенство...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, Я проверил, опечатка, там `y[i]>-15`. Но это не повлияло на ситуацию, все так же, при попадании точки на ось ОУ он не показывает что это граница. Изначально этот блок, должен быть вот таким вот
`(x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]>=0) or
                   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]=-14) or
                   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]=round(-b/2)) or
                   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]=round(b/2))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Итак, формулирую условие задачи. На координатной оси с центром в точке `(0, 0)` задана окружность радиуса `R`. Внутри окружности находится прямоугольник с координатами диагонали `Rect = ((Left, Top), (Right, Bottom))`. Требуется для точки `(x, y)` определить принадлежность одной из следующих зон

- Вне окружности
- На окружности
- Внутри окружности
- На границе прямоугольника
- Внутри прямоугольника

Решение:

```
type
  TZone = (zOut, zCircle, zCircleIn, zRect, zRectInt);
  TZoneSegment = (zsOut, zsBorder, zsIn);

// Проверка принадлежности точки отрезку
function TestSegment(const APoint, AFrom, ATo: Double): TZoneSegment;
begin
  if SameValue(APoint, AFrom) or SameValue(APoint, ATo) then
    Result := zsBorder
  else if (APoint > AFrom) and (APoint < ATo) then
    Result := zsIn
  else
    Result := zsOut;
end;

function TestZone(const APoint: TPoint; const ARadius: Double; const ARect: TRect): TZone;
var
  LRadiusVector: Double;
  LXSegment, LYSegment: TZoneSegment;
begin
  LRadiusVector := Sqrt(Sqr(APoint.X) + Sqr(APoint.Y));
  if SameValue(LRadiusVector, ARadius) then
    Result := zCircle
  else if LRadiusVector > ARadius then
    Result := zOut
  else begin
    LXSegment := TestSegment(APoint.X, ARect.Left, ARect.Right);
    LYSegment := TestSegment(APoint.Y, ARect.Top, ARect.Bottom);
    // Если точка лежит внутри каждого отрезка сторон
    if (LXSegment = zsIn) and (LYSegment = zsIn) then
      Result := zRectIn  // то она лежит внутри прямоугольника
    // Если точка лежит снаружи хотя бы одного отрезка сторон
    else if (LXSegment = zsOut) or (LYSegment = zsOut) then
      Result := zCircleIn // то она лежит внутри прямоугольника
    else
      Result := zRect;  // Точка лежит внутри одной стороны и на границе другой
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Условие`(x[i]=0) and (y[i]<15) and (y[i]=15)` неверно , оно никогда не выполняется. видимо, опечатка

Comment: Я проверил, я так и писал. Изначально этот блок, должен быть вот таким вот
`(x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]>=0) or
                   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]=-14) or
                   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]=round(-b/2)) or
                   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]=round(b/2))`